# Rails cannot render created_at attribute of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, rendering

This is so strange hence I can render every other part of the Message object BUT the datetime fields.... Heres is the offending code:

```
<h2><%= message.created_at.to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:long)%></h2>
```

It complains about no such method .datetime for Null.class. I tried rendering just message.created_at and there is nothing showing up. I have implemented this while back and it worked fine, any changes I have missed in Rails framework?

EDIT: Looked under my deployed app in active admin and all timestamps are gone like I cannot see them as well.

Comment: Do you have created_at and updated_at fields in schema.rb?

Comment: I do have those fields there. They are both datetime. I can see the dates in SQLite Manager but not on the site its extremely strange...

Answer (score 1):

Well this line been breaking it all along.... (config/application.rb)

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

I was trying to set timezone for time to display correctly but I guess that was not the way to go.